# How To Acess Element in Var - JSON API Response [C#]

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to get number of tweets here is progress I have made so far

```
string jsonString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=" + isValidUri);

            var jsonresult = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = jsonresult.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

and when I run it result var gets the two elements one is count and another one site site address now I am trying to acess the count element but I am not able to figure out can anyone help ?

Comment: You can debug your code and get type of `result` at runtime. I do not know this `JavaScriptSerializer`, but, probably, it is `dynamic` type or `Dictionary<string, object>`. Try to cast it to dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`.  To get the `count` element, do

```
var value = result["count"];
```

If its an integer then

```
var value = (int) result["count"];
```

Comment: i am getting this error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type"

Comment: Cast it before doing so: 
`var result = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsonresult.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`